# A view with exposed sort: can i turn off 'grouping field' for different sort criteria?

Tags: views

My Views list of events is grouped by the date (using the Grouping Field checkbox in the Style settings).

*But* my exposed Sort Criteria can sort the list by either date or by name.

**An alphabetical list of events grouped by date really doesn't make any sense.**

What would make sense is for the Grouping Field to turn off when the Sort Criteria is by name.

I'm thinking either i do two views, and my template decides which view to embed depending on the URL query. Or perhaps a views hook like **hook_views_query_alter()** could turn off the Grouping Field depending on the circumstances?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i think i've managed it with a Views hook. Took an hour's worth of tinkering. I plopped this into my template.php...

```
/** Find out what the sort criterion is.
    @return The sort criterion fieldname. IMPORTANT: this isn't sanitised!
*/
function MYTHEME_get_sort_by() {
    if (isset($_GET['sort_by']))
        return $_GET['sort_by'];    
}

/** Turn off Views grouping-field when sorting by title.
*/
function MYTHEME_views_pre_build(&$view) {
    if ($view->name=='event_programme') {
        if (MYTHEME_get_sort_by()=='title')
            $view->display_handler->options['style_options']['grouping']='';    
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: i'm using Drupal 6.22, Views 3.0rc2